# R: passing character vector as a function parameter

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to learn how to create my own functions.

While the following function works fine:

```
#---------------------
# this works fine
#---------------------
func <- function(df) {
  
 new_df <- unite(df, key, c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width"), sep = " ", remove = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)
 
 return(new_df)
 
}

new_iris <- func(iris)
```

, this function where the unite function's third argument is now parameterized:

```
#---------------------
# this does not work
#---------------------
func <- function(df, keycols) {
  
 new_df <- unite(df, key, keycols, sep = " ", remove = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)
 
 return(new_df)
 
}

keycols <- quote(c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width"))

new_iris <- func(iris, keycols)
```

generates the following error message:

*Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `language`.
i It must be numeric or character.*

Is there a way to pass c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width") as a parameter? Or some way to make the keycols a parameter for the above user defined function?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Try not to `quote`, the error message is clear about the need of a numeric or *character*  vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may adopt either of these methods

```r
library(tidyr)
func <- function(df, ...){
  unite(df, key, ..., sep=" ", remove = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)
}

func(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
#>         key Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1   5.1 3.5          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 2     4.9 3          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 3   4.7 3.2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa



keycols <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")

func <- function(df, cols){
  unite(df, key, !!cols, sep=" ", remove = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)
}

func(iris, keycols)
#>         key Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1   5.1 3.5          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 2     4.9 3          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 3   4.7 3.2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 4   4.6 3.1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve this simply by using curly-curly `{{}}` from rlang package which is a safe option,

```r
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)

iris <- tibble::as_tibble(iris)


# using curly curly from {rlang} ------------------------------------------

func <- function(df, keycols) {
  
  new_df <- unite(df, "key", {{keycols}}, sep = " ", remove = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)
  
  return(new_df)
  
}

func(iris, c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) # passing directly the columns

#> # A tibble: 150 × 6
#>    key     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>    <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1 5.1 3.5          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2 4.9 3            4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3 4.7 3.2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4 4.6 3.1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5 5 3.6            5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6 5.4 3.9          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7 4.6 3.4          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8 5 3.4            5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9 4.4 2.9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10 4.9 3.1          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # … with 140 more rows

func(iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")) # passing columns as character vector

#> # A tibble: 150 × 6
#>    key     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>    <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1 5.1 3.5          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2 4.9 3            4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3 4.7 3.2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4 4.6 3.1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5 5 3.6            5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6 5.4 3.9          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7 4.6 3.4          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8 5 3.4            5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9 4.4 2.9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10 4.9 3.1          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # … with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

> To understand why and how this solution works, look here [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)